# backbone view extend from two view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have two backbone view and I want to use third view which will be extended from both

view1 = Backbone.View.extend({});
view2 = Backbone.View.extend({});
view3 (extended from view1 and view2)
Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it but this should work, taken from: https://gist.github.com/alassek/1227770

```
(function () {

  function extendEach () {
    var args  = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        child = this;

    _.each(args, function (proto) {
      child = child.extend(proto);
    });

    return child;
  }

  Backbone.Model.extendEach        =
    Backbone.Collection.extendEach =
    Backbone.Router.extendEach     =
    Backbone.View.extendEach       = extendEach;

})();

ClassC = Backbone.Model.extendEach(ClassA, ClassB, [properties])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution much easier, in your case would be:

```
_.extend(view3.prototype, view1.prototype, view2.prototype);
```

Example for Backbone:
http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1809/

Example for Marionette:
http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1810/

Also you can do this:

```
view3.extend(view1.prototype);
view3.extend(view2.prototype);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M5J8Q/1811/

Greetings!